# Dynamic Query performance comparison in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I create a Sql Dynamic query by the following way(I am using Stored Procedure), but i want to know, is it have any performance degradation in comparison of that dynamic query which we execute in string form by **`sp_Executesql`** `sp`.

```
SELECT   *
FROM CityToCityTransferPricing as ctp
INNER JOIN VehicleDynamicPackage as vdp on ctp.vehicleId=vdp.vehicleId
INNER JOIN VehicleType as vt on vdp.vehicleTypeId=vt.vehicleTypeId
WHERE cityToCityTransferID=@cityToCityTransferID 
    AND (
        @vehicleID is null 
        OR ctp.vehicleId=@vehicleID
    )       
    AND (
        @status is null 
        OR ctp.status=@status
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, you will not see significant performance degradation, when using dynamic queries.

And also see this -

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.CityToCityTransferPricing ctp 
JOIN dbo.VehicleDynamicPackage vdp ON ctp.vehicleId = vdp.vehicleId 
JOIN dbo.VehicleType vt ON vdp.vehicleTypeId = vt.vehicleTypeId
WHERE cityToCityTransferID = @cityToCityTransferID
    AND ISNULL(@vehicleID, ctp.vehicleId) = ctp.vehicleId
    AND ISNULL(@status, ctp.[status]) = ctp.[status]
```

Comment: How much it cost less, when it is a simple query and we use 
ctp.vehicleId=@vehicleID in place of
ISNULL(@vehicleID, ctp.vehicleId) = ctp.vehicleId

Comment: You will not see differences in query execution time. This is only a good coding style :)

Comment: ok, N this is my requirement, by passing null ,i remove that particular where condition :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no general answer that can fit all cases. Best thing you can do is to check execution plan and see for yourself. I do agree with Devart that in most cases you probably won’t notice any difference.

Here is a good reading on dynamics sql: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 1):

You must know that dynamic SQL will ALWAYS be recompiled. So  performance wise it is not a good thing. In this case you might not notice it, but i would still go for the most best practice, not using dynamic sql.

Also, if you really must use a dynamic query you might also look into the sp_executesql vs EXEC. EXEC will also always give you a new fresh query plan (no caching), where sp_executesql compiles the query the first time and reuse its plan the 2nd time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using parameterised `sp_execute_sql`, it does not make much difference. But if you are generating dynamic string on the fly and then executing it, there could be a performance impact. Please see the following link : [Dynamic SQL Performance comparison](http://www.tectalks.com/406/dynamic-sql-performance-comparison/)